# Blender resources for architects?

Tags: modeling

My interest in Blender comes from wanting to use it to model physical structures and produce architectural drawings; what I have so far is really impressive, but there doesn't seem to be too much information about my particular interest.

Are there any (Blender-) resources that would be particularly useful for architects? E.g. packages of standard 'elements' like windows, doors, roofs or whatever, or perhaps a discussion group specifically for architects?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender stackexchange. It seems you are asking lots of questions at the same time. Try narrowing it down and dividing it into several question.

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/341/are-questions-about-external-tutorial-resources-on-topic it has 10 times more views than other questions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Some resources

### Add-ons

- [Archimesh for creating architecture elements](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/10/29/archimesh-add-on-creates-architectural-elements/)

  - [Download](https://github.com/Antonioya/blender/tree/master/archimesh)
- [Window Generator](http://www.blendernation.com/2012/11/01/window-generator-new-interface-window-styles/)
- [Chimney Generator](http://vimeo.com/75140413)
- [Jamb Generator](http://vimeo.com/71163940)
- [Balcony Generator](http://vimeo.com/35525542)

### Sites:

- [Blender 3D Architect](http://www.blender3darchitect.com/)

### Video Tutorials:

- [Blenderguru: The complete architecture series](http://www.blenderguru.com/the-complete-architecture-series/)
   ***Edit:**This tutorial dates back to 2010, the rendering lessons use an external render engine since Cycles wasn't available. (Edited May 3rd 2016).*
- [Cgcookie: Interior 3d architectural visualization](http://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-courses/interior-3d-architectural-visualization/)

  ***Edit:**CGcookie are no longer streaming this tutorial as " it's time for it to be put to rest" yet ZIP files are available to download the lessons.(Edited May 3rd 2016).*

### Related questions:

- [How to model effectively using exact measurements?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/what-are-some-best-practices-when-modelling-with-exact-measurements)
- [How do blender units and meters, feet, or yards correlate?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254/how-do-blender-units-and-meters-feet-or-yards-correlate/258#258)
- [Is there any way to measure angle between edges/faces, or change the angle so that the mesh changes according to the angle we input?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/is-there-any-way-to-measure-angle-between-edges-faces-or-change-the-angle-so-th)

Answer (score 7):

I can't believe no one has mentioned [Microvellum](http://www.blendernation.com/2014/01/24/interior-design-and-architectural-rendering-with-microvellum-and-blender/) yet... maybe it's just too specific to interiors, but it looks incredibly powerful.

Answer (score 5):

[This](http://rift3d.com/architectural-add-ons-for-blender/) link pretty much summerises the best addons for Blender to speed up architectural work. And [this youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUoJMye2LuZQ1b6xBSEbbow?feature=watch) shows how to use the Archimesh addon. If you are new to Blender, you should try googling beginner tutorials for Blender to make yourself familiar with its concepts. [BlenderGuru](http://www.blenderguru.com/) tutorials are popular for example.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend using the [Sweethome](http://www.sweethome3d.com/userGuide.jsp#exportToOBJ) editor for things like floor plans and basic furniture. Environments can be exported into Blender.

Answer (score 2):

An add-on, called "sun position", will position the sun for architectural ( or other purposes ) based on location, time, and date.

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Sun_Position

Answer (score -4):

I suggest [Yobi3D - 3D model search engine](https://www.yobi3d.com) to look for 3D models on the internet.  There are tons of windows, chairs, and architecture related 3D models.  The site provides a 3D viewer, so that you can see the models in 3D on browser.

- I'm the founder of Yobi3D.com

Comment: While you have mentioned your affiliation on your About Me, please also include the full disclosure on the answer. Otherwise, it can be seen as an attempt to spam. Please refer to [how to not be a spammer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Comment: As you mentioned, it's a viewer, linked to other sites, that may or may not have a download button available, and each site or model has a different license, looking for a model is tedious since after searching through all available models, you don't know if you'll be able to get that model, or if it's just a spam site that collects hits for SEO! Well I tried one of the links and I got a website in Chinese with tons of ads.

Comment: Hi, the linked site will always have a download link/button somewhere.  Some sites requires registration, some don't.  Sometimes the source site is down, we remove from our index as soon as possible.