# Cartoon series - Resources all in one

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I was working to achieve a cartoon series using Blender, where as I am still struggling with many things and each problem arises after one another.

Is it possible for us (All the respected members) to make a list of the skills and resources required to complete the life cycle of a cartoon series? [Something like this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7657/blender-resources-for-architects)

Like what basic skills required for it (Modeling, rigging, animation) dependency of the textures and story etc.

So it will be help full for a bigger to use blender from start to end and execute the life cycle.

Comment: Try fixing the words in your question. Who is "us" and what is a "list down" check your grammar and spelling.

Comment: Are you saying something like an animator's tool box and essential guide to make animations with Blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete set of skills are those necessary to make a movie plus those necessary to model 3D objects plus those necessary to rig and animate characters. Borrowing from Sidney Lumet's "Making Movies" the movie making skills include

- writing the story. This is the most important.
- directing
- set design
- lighting
- cinematography
- art direction
- foley (sound effects)
- scoring (writing the music)
- editing
  The skills related to 3d animation include
- creating materials and textures
- creating the 3d objects
- rigging, with face rigging being a whole category
- character animation, with face animation being a whole category

There are many good books and online tutorials on movie making, 3d modeling, and animation.